# Scale object with edge loop as if there were no loops

Tags: modeling, scale

I have a cylinder, that have been split with multiple edge loops.

Is it possible to scale the bottom part of it as if it were no intermediate edge loops.

Comment: Please add images to show what you mean. A bit unclear at the minute. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the proportional editing. So you edit the base loop and it influences also other loops:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works. Is it exact though, even with the proper falloff?